# Loop through the children host group ansible is failing

Tags: ansible

My inventory file is having below host groups:

```
[uat1]
123.11.23.22 ansible_user="xxx"

[OS_uat2]
123.45.6.7 ansible_user="yyy"

[uat1_childs:children]
uat1
OS_uat2
```

I am having the vars file which is having param for below hosts. I am running a playbook to run a shell command. I am passing some parameters with the playbook. I am passing deployment_environment as **uat1_childs**. This is giving me error. Playbook is:

```
- name: play to ping test
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: "{{ deployment_environment }}"
  ignore_unreachable: yes

  vars_files:
  - r_params.yml

  vars:
    package: "{{ package }}"

  tasks:
  
  - set_fact:
        env_param: "{{ deployment_environment }}"
        
  - name: ping test
    ping:
      data: pong

  - name: Deploy Services on "{{ deployment_environment }}"
    shell: cd "{{ env_select[env_param].script_path }}"; sh "{{ env_select[env_param].script_path }}/deploy.sh" "param1" "param2" "{{ env_select[env_param].repo }}" "{{ artifact_version }}" "{{ env_select[env_param].ENV }}" "{{ arti_username }}" "{{ arti_pass }}" "{{ deployer }}"  "{{ package }}" "{{ env_select[env_param].deployment_path }}"
    when: (package == "abc")
    with_items: "{{ groups[{{ 'deployment_environment' }}] }}"
```

This is giving me error as:

```
fatal: [123.11.23.22]: FAILED! =>
{
    "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'deployment_environment'"
}
fatal: [123.45.6.7]: FAILED! =>
{
    "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'deployment_environment'"
}
```

I tried removing apostrophe in with items, still it is giving me error. Cant identify how to run the task in all children host group.

Comment: `{{ 'deployment_environment' }}` is the literal string `'deployment_environment'`, not a variable named `deployment_environment`. What you are looking to do is `"{{ groups[deployment_environment] }}"`.

Comment: This is trying to search the host group name like, OS_uat2 and not its hostname. This is failing to connect to ssh.

Comment: Because your approach is all wrong. Ansible is made to connect to some nodes, if you want to act on those hosts, target them in the `hosts` already, do not try to do black magic in obscure shell scripts.